# Sql server Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I m passing a variable to stored procedure, i want the proc to make a look up to another table and get the primary key of the table and insert that value to the table.

```
Table A:
pk_id int,
user varchar

Table B:
userKey int
locationKey int    
Someotherthings varchar

Table C:
pk_id int,
Location varchar
```

When i invoke sp_howto, and pass user to it, i want to it to get the pk_id from table A and insert it to table B userKey.

```
set @res = select pk_id from TableA where user=@user
set @loc = select pk_id from TableC where location = @Location
insert into tableB (userKey, locationKey) values (@res, @loc)
```

Does this work? and **what if I have many variables I want to populate like this?**

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "many keys" Do you mean you want to do this for many pairs of tables?

Comment: edited the question one more time.

Comment: My last edit does this - try it - but if there's no structural relation between TableA and TableC, you really should do it in two statements rather than one. I'm going to add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The question has mutated some--the currently posted code works fine, these are alternatives.*

The one-statement way, where you pass two parameters, @User and @Location:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (UserKey, LocationKey)
SELECT (userKey, LocationKey) 
FROM
(
    (select pk_id as userKey, user from TableA) x
    cross join 
    (select pk_id as LocationKey, Location from TableC) y
    WHERE user = @user and location = @location
)
```

If if User is unique in TableA, and Location is unique in TableC, this will insert one record into TableB.

**Edited to add:**

The above will do it in a single statement, but the added complexity gains you nothing. Better to do it like this:

Add a unique key to TableB:

```
pk_id int IDENTITY
```

Then do your insert like this:

```
declare @newID int

INSERT INTO TableB (UserKey)
SELECT pk_id from TableA where user = @user

SELECT @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- retrieves the new key value

UPDATE TableB set LocationKey = 
    (SELECT pk_id from TableC WHERE location = @location)
WHERE pk_id = @newID
```

Comment: what s wrong with my approach, i havent tried it yet, but would it work?

Comment: Yes--I thought you were looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

The more succinct syntax is to use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (UserKey)
SELECT UserKey FROM TableA WHERE User = @User
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for one or more keys

```
insert into tableB (userKey) 
select  userKey from TableA where user=@user
```